# How to extract links from HTML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use regex function in python to filter out links from the html that I scraped on eBay website.

My question is how can I filter out those links with using following pattern: https://www.ebay.com/itm/ + all other characters.

I am getting successfully the https://www.ebay.com/itm/ part but I am not sure how to do the rest.

Python version that I am using: 3.8.8.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=Universal+Adjustable+Hand+Shower+Holder+Suction+Cup+Holder+Full+Plating+Shower+Rail+Head+Holder+Bathroom+Bracket+Stable+rotation&_sacat=0'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.find_all('li')
pattern = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/'

results = re.findall('https://www.ebay.com/itm/', str(listings))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get links that starts with `https://www.ebay.com/itm/` you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=Universal+Adjustable+Hand+Shower+Holder+Suction+Cup+Holder+Full+Plating+Shower+Rail+Head+Holder+Bathroom+Bracket+Stable+rotation&_sacat=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.select("li a")

for a in listings:
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/"):
        print(link)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/01920391?epid=26039819083&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item3b542eae7a:g:FQkAAOSwK21gKvEZ&amdata=enc%3AAQAFAAACcBaobrjLl8XobRIiIML1V4Imu%252Fn%252BzU5L90Z278x5ickkrDx%252B2NLp21dg6hHbHAkGMYdiW1E6zjXxnQ0bf7c%252Fx%252Fvs5PW%252FYFw1ZdbGMi8wsGV6qXw8OFLl4Os1ACX3bnQxFkVpRib9hMb5gVyLha4q9L0xiporu5InbX0LrSgg7nCCCwtC7y3vOE3hc8PszsrXWLb5KFdj7%252BD98et12MdkEfMPFhJZuS%252BkFsp2esVTRCYctOhcwzPSdfzCOYprlr2miQc4czCv1Tcfs3LKUPJn8uQyRc%252BAnKY1oyTeYnJ7wYuGkBU%252FSVYjziLBaPhT%252FlVu0hR9ZX6OnAeRaJ1g0iCaDjrRXEXRwUO87riWeI8kExm1zzY7QicPeMnfWZdBvVhg05GOScPOlLTVPHakqGLX0y2GUXV6fkTLua3nSF5YBmLX%252FqdCxT6yS0dutVs5MPWvQYlN474hUzbubkZVAs7Y%252BBBEsHrGjVzCj0szZ6w1%252BHgkV5O9jrXGnyew5%252Bnxy7VCq5xEkUDIt1nSg996AeDksNmSNumhfsIOGltIXbqAbjqEUpPcVO%252BDPymxlh0iMxCZQalYnmljBRzKILYWkES0vfA14Gh5E7KWrztdC6WzEEFtgVuABakQ1eAOZnuEueqK6IakC%252BIfRbXv96Tv01IPDvwPeM8wMo6j8bMjY3D5KHS5EXPVdHKUnjCJiYCcVUqcKwhL6eN2MZ%252Bn9yxmWESUPN394NPrX%252FI2z7t0Bbo7iqmsWNQcyi0EHzDwJPMK%252FNSif8%252F2adRF7dT1JrbL9sryKSN2kv9OsdGQ0fMMC1LV3Ph43HivUJdqkgjGxqEqX5v1xQ%253D%253D%7Ccksum%3A25481541593068896952f4834d93a0bb998f5b5ba5fe%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
https://www.ebay.com/itm/333909214974?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item4dbe8a46fe:g:wjYAAOSwXZtgQKMK&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAADAPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsSprd4IgPv6LBzlteBBg9Pe7gpGas6KEYWvIQmgmNrIcf1ZIcLwSyYlVIojBTlJPAd4XoDj5k2AzULwOu2K1678su8RhEOIAhD%252FWN3J3erMgWugg2CT0y8zcUjbbWHtNfzYrnVuG%252FUvWmYzvxdGvHZvRdzha0juBNJzGKXnChJ6MECxb2uzy5G631xzrIxblEW3AM1ogDVv19il%252Fn7Vlzr0cERgdjLqGUj5KIynU8Xj9sHRx%252F%252FcSxPq8W4v1RHP%252FYZQhE4keU2U3pZGBCy9hyaYaf5pr78zEcjg2aoyh%252B6DUFkxtjTnmPhNqiwO5QNkl21UaDagoNQYRkZb4iW0QpXX628qHxIqBVL4GjtRczXt%252Bi0ZVn0B6GBqNzHtHarXqCSe7966rspJOMXwYB%252Fj3m%252Fpe3oJO8dKBNDmzxUNhnE4Bf76ZlFiW%252Fh9TXWEO3vdhLjRjjmjJKjgj7IXVorj%252BypBfHCbTXCA7nHsBSsOdNR%252B3LopnwoQutVCsk%252FQ8bESJCn0unvLARcM6wBRakZl3Uxhe1iSnMV%252F69vpTVm2XC1ZjU0IzF7xB5laYPRPcrOwXSJHwZJHkwyziteo%252FWBZNkklgTjY%252BdEanyHKlzppyJWLAufvIbWt4YWy3Xz%252FAKaKScpMGsHWNqEKwGJ%252BPeSFwq57qnm5xK0InzfsHtyVHd6lWoaKqyP8e7nVQBjqfNciDdLD5D3fuiIHQupPyX2m1Z%252B%252FeQOayocP6GV%252BAfSHCS44Y%252Fgh4njFjCVO5KAR%252BZXiNddo%252BfFGSpUZO1q38Cq3MDvyeRF3vYd2r3FNaimwBT2d3%252Fnl3seechJuFBWHONudGgMuSiXwoy66SbYwIj0CD427%252B1FVDHw%252F4LSkJhi78oWKX2I9sGnvHrj4boKie6mlPN6ZGOenVXOpLWNK8ZSN%252FzEqUzt6iC32EFb8rj%252FC4HK9AWddRejsdJHnsFKs7QAysEUN%252Fh6ltSA3FR64qww0Qvp3A%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
https://www.ebay.com/itm/333909214974?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item4dbe8a46fe:g:wjYAAOSwXZtgQKMK&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAADAPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsSprd4IgPv6LBzlteBBg9Pe7gpGas6KEYWvIQmgmNrIcf1ZIcLwSyYlVIojBTlJPAd4XoDj5k2AzULwOu2K1678su8RhEOIAhD%252FWN3J3erMgWugg2CT0y8zcUjbbWHtNfzYrnVuG%252FUvWmYzvxdGvHZvRdzha0juBNJzGKXnChJ6MECxb2uzy5G631xzrIxblEW3AM1ogDVv19il%252Fn7Vlzr0cERgdjLqGUj5KIynU8Xj9sHRx%252F%252FcSxPq8W4v1RHP%252FYZQhE4keU2U3pZGBCy9hyaYaf5pr78zEcjg2aoyh%252B6DUFkxtjTnmPhNqiwO5QNkl21UaDagoNQYRkZb4iW0QpXX628qHxIqBVL4GjtRczXt%252Bi0ZVn0B6GBqNzHtHarXqCSe7966rspJOMXwYB%252Fj3m%252Fpe3oJO8dKBNDmzxUNhnE4Bf76ZlFiW%252Fh9TXWEO3vdhLjRjjmjJKjgj7IXVorj%252BypBfHCbTXCA7nHsBSsOdNR%252B3LopnwoQutVCsk%252FQ8bESJCn0unvLARcM6wBRakZl3Uxhe1iSnMV%252F69vpTVm2XC1ZjU0IzF7xB5laYPRPcrOwXSJHwZJHkwyziteo%252FWBZNkklgTjY%252BdEanyHKlzppyJWLAufvIbWt4YWy3Xz%252FAKaKScpMGsHWNqEKwGJ%252BPeSFwq57qnm5xK0InzfsHtyVHd6lWoaKqyP8e7nVQBjqfNciDdLD5D3fuiIHQupPyX2m1Z%252B%252FeQOayocP6GV%252BAfSHCS44Y%252Fgh4njFjCVO5KAR%252BZXiNddo%252BfFGSpUZO1q38Cq3MDvyeRF3vYd2r3FNaimwBT2d3%252Fnl3seechJuFBWHONudGgMuSiXwoy66SbYwIj0CD427%252B1FVDHw%252F4LSkJhi78oWKX2I9sGnvHrj4boKie6mlPN6ZGOenVXOpLWNK8ZSN%252FzEqUzt6iC32EFb8rj%252FC4HK9AWddRejsdJHnsFKs7QAysEUN%252Fh6ltSA3FR64qww0Qvp3A%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
https://www.ebay.com/itm/313269877281?hash=item48f056fa21:g:hd0AAOSwz6tfknZF
https://www.ebay.com/itm/313269877281?hash=item48f056fa21:g:hd0AAOSwz6tfknZF
https://www.ebay.com/itm/184741430233?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item2b037283d9:g:TyQAAOSwVYBgZxlp&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAADAPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsS7UXID%252BRPOSNsnm8kYPghtOhpdocScHh%252BDgY2CTi3nJTgQcXQEKAs8Ix13gdusXFa3yngmHdTBh2vatEHVnazTxou3w%252FDC26a237oG00lpNN0M8zpUGIN9nYQpAgSrl8Z2cNTqgManH1%252Bz3LIm4YNAlHJk%252BHZA8%252FzFNts2J8C7tWjwB%252FA16vRrvHG7nYYLh0tdLtgbf0dpc2Qe9fAJlzaEBwz89Vmv30NMzTFBw4HT%252FzDvPHrTnvmygxCs75Law6GL0yq5FZiufYo%252Fj1bGviIrCjul2tV%252FqMzojlafc7De3fEH0%252Fx7e%252B3S%252BRPOUwrq%252BjDlOH8%252Bp7tZBwZd70GEYnMNBPUFcFmnDcsZgJhS4xnlt5ibp7JgMABsL7TnNK6pm0ran5wu7KVyRsCnTEkWCx0WZ9emEe1xzzVQrJt%252B7ICl%252FNqMq9gaz3%252F2O%252B4Zf83FlMWgd2K0kvtYiBYlFzRZTKrLIkJUl9pDo8nYDJROrSUnT3xZdDu38mqKft9ckuwd8LsRn8emIR%252BJJQi2I6M1gWYnuPrD09rQQMKD7FA2VxWfA4JfePSSoAwyFVyvOkYN47cJkG3ymeQJZUZOFXt8h2j%252F3b0KlMlImQcYcancrGMk7cx4AfUBca%252BSPEC8e3w2RIDzp62%252F9If%252FVLm6Vq6rvdjjspmxA9r2LErZAgEIu6%252BXWuF3eicCrtX9dQic3TmmPPeordO3nK2QKgdSc487ywrfOX9i5XmQqmFmOyN5W%252B%252FwDmeGHmb1l1KPnWa14048eIHqDITTFibsKyRk7H04VwWrkqhfOxsrek7VxmnK7Ciqgli22Se7VPqPhlVRddgYe%252FIvp5Yw8%252BGoewf4mpOiRQ%252Bmm5QpRVpA%252BusDd2id6Gz2crCd%252FnoYT9shk8tfXCfGwFson3CxpgjeSoLd1tsQ%252FeY0qgZelpVjKdZ%252BeaaJpiC1uKa4r5FZxxJ0b5VxYp8j6F9255HFQGZzAQ2MVJyu647sA%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
https://www.ebay.com/itm/184741430233?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item2b037283d9:g:TyQAAOSwVYBgZxlp&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAADAPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsS7UXID%252BRPOSNsnm8kYPghtOhpdocScHh%252BDgY2CTi3nJTgQcXQEKAs8Ix13gdusXFa3yngmHdTBh2vatEHVnazTxou3w%252FDC26a237oG00lpNN0M8zpUGIN9nYQpAgSrl8Z2cNTqgManH1%252Bz3LIm4YNAlHJk%252BHZA8%252FzFNts2J8C7tWjwB%252FA16vRrvHG7nYYLh0tdLtgbf0dpc2Qe9fAJlzaEBwz89Vmv30NMzTFBw4HT%252FzDvPHrTnvmygxCs75Law6GL0yq5FZiufYo%252Fj1bGviIrCjul2tV%252FqMzojlafc7De3fEH0%252Fx7e%252B3S%252BRPOUwrq%252BjDlOH8%252Bp7tZBwZd70GEYnMNBPUFcFmnDcsZgJhS4xnlt5ibp7JgMABsL7TnNK6pm0ran5wu7KVyRsCnTEkWCx0WZ9emEe1xzzVQrJt%252B7ICl%252FNqMq9gaz3%252F2O%252B4Zf83FlMWgd2K0kvtYiBYlFzRZTKrLIkJUl9pDo8nYDJROrSUnT3xZdDu38mqKft9ckuwd8LsRn8emIR%252BJJQi2I6M1gWYnuPrD09rQQMKD7FA2VxWfA4JfePSSoAwyFVyvOkYN47cJkG3ymeQJZUZOFXt8h2j%252F3b0KlMlImQcYcancrGMk7cx4AfUBca%252BSPEC8e3w2RIDzp62%252F9If%252FVLm6Vq6rvdjjspmxA9r2LErZAgEIu6%252BXWuF3eicCrtX9dQic3TmmPPeordO3nK2QKgdSc487ywrfOX9i5XmQqmFmOyN5W%252B%252FwDmeGHmb1l1KPnWa14048eIHqDITTFibsKyRk7H04VwWrkqhfOxsrek7VxmnK7Ciqgli22Se7VPqPhlVRddgYe%252FIvp5Yw8%252BGoewf4mpOiRQ%252Bmm5QpRVpA%252BusDd2id6Gz2crCd%252FnoYT9shk8tfXCfGwFson3CxpgjeSoLd1tsQ%252FeY0qgZelpVjKdZ%252BeaaJpiC1uKa4r5FZxxJ0b5VxYp8j6F9255HFQGZzAQ2MVJyu647sA%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
https://www.ebay.com/itm/154108126132?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item23e18f63b4:g:5g0AAOSwkApfch0l&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAADAPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsStEKTPzZMfQmny3knR97t0JsD6L97oauzovvk2KO0WEt%252Fy1DvPmlzbWssMnX7EK9TVYjaGDcIoX%252FGC%252FmDBJiZuzo4Q57rySuBn9egod2B14d0XvKYJrNvSErcJ2RIJIQABAo473RTmNDf6Ql8ivp1PqCbAFg3a3CFzJJNK1in5oOpyIPlur6D%252BrPTA0SbM8%252F6ryLrpO9VpOBncBnX3aQFMBkALPsmmbolhK1Z2wtACsanrnaWudSur0%252BWE2VNOx8K2DSdSW7FqtEDE0lE%252F%252FUhnHvrdqsLg%252F1GsgbpoyWNV1TSap52SOr0Ndsb6HhxIaOdngXwWmW%252BD4qbhHsUxFesHcMrPsOtlb7gIRYj5ubReQpvgK9GiBSCwiEBMUcODZoXhNEsXp9MiBZF9qeWKTApnNy3pbBWAI65p3v0TiawoyWN%252BGywOpl8laWKrZseCWQMn4o0ZmSC08wU%252Fj7Zn2biBdULHfRiJm%252FPvDzSeAVy92JchTe69dUO9%252BHL7%252B5zurnYfPEjLiOaKhHW60bbsO3ru3PZ1RMwF4iMxP%252FgGIKc8xk11Zsms1%252BGfiApbCy7rQraZPQBzQJpzQOIzd7xrkPyOBuNjj2HdPE7bZjLGOCjuIYDIuBxCP0ZMajblQrr5pzvUjdMT4zJ76GmJ28qGDm5TkxD8tDv0eaWnBfDssMpHtAW8GND7g3hE%252Fhqvoc2072E78fzVz0Ts51H%252BW77rrbpC9DmtLHopXEp5fCMcP3vuTv%252BaCqKuaMuy8blc6S6ldjbuqSkRe5qtI5edG5HeingADQenYM%252FbViMlpVwv1ul9GZquueAo89zMOUKKRhsfq6oP4LyLN6%252BNUcOoAxOSBMw7bWC7oYD5yilolDFw7RauJooyv3wMOuZLCABtjABogDu63sdJpcNptiYVj84nsGwDi4AJ4uTPjw1jItB87NskmHFAyY2sdHH%252Be3OqwybMZKg7OKXzx2WPSDPVdN2K5TjZA%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a more efficient filtering within css using ^ starts with operator to identify the appropriate links starting with that string. Use a set comprehension to return only unique items.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

```
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=Universal+Adjustable+Hand+Shower+Holder+Suction+Cup+Holder+Full+Plating+Shower+Rail+Head+Holder+Bathroom+Bracket+Stable+rotation&_sacat=0'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")
links = {i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href^="https://www.ebay.com/itm/"]')}
print(links)
```

If you wish to specify the href is a descendant of a li then add that into the selector with a descendant combinator and type selector:

```
links = {i['href'] for i in soup.select('li [href^="https://www.ebay.com/itm/"]')}
```